# Use nginx location to look for another directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, nginx, devops

I can't use nginx location to point all image paths starting with **https://mydomain.fr/uploads/projects/** to the directory **/var/www/mydomain.fr/back/uploads/projects**

My nginx server is running a static react application and an nodejs api (with proxy_pass).
The api and the application work well, only the images are a problem (404).
I'm new to nginx.
Thanks for your help !

I tried this configuration but location /uploads/projects/ doesn't works.

```js
server {
        server_name mydomain.fr www.mydomain.fr;
        location /robots.txt {
        return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /";
        }
        location / {
        root /var/www/mydomain.fr/front/dist;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        location /uploads/projects/ {
        root /var/www/mydomain.fr/back/uploads/projects;
        try_files $uri = 404;
        }
        location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mydomain.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name mydomain.fr www.mydomain.fr;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Comment: `/uploads/projects` is part of the URL, so it should **not** be in the `root` statement. Try: `root /var/www/mydomain.fr/back;`